# API keys in GCP API Gateway - 300 limit

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, key, token, gateway

I am building an api service. All api endpoints are fronted by GCP api gateway. All my customers  will be given a unique api key to access my api endpoints. Google cloud allows me to generate unique API keys using the Credential service in API & Service. but there is a limit of 300  API keys. How do I bypass this limit? How do people handle api keys for clients nowadays?

ps: APIGEE is way to complicated and costly. Implementing my own custom solution in the backend is a time consuming option I don't currently have.

Comment: Create another project and create API keys on that project! And why do you need different keys? Do you authenticate each customer with their own key?

Comment: Yes. I authenticate each customer with their own long lived api key so I can track their usage. Your suggestion of creating another project every 300 customers is not feasible, I will have to load balance across multiple gateways in different accounts and I will not know which account the end user api key is.

Comment: Do you really track each customer with different API Keys on the same project?

Comment: as an example. https://home.openweathermap.org/api_keys

Comment: AFAIK, API Gateway use API key to authenticate a project on GCP. If you have 300 keys on the same project, you will identify the same project and won't be able to distinguish the key used. It's true at least for quotas. Maybe you track your key differently.

Answer (score 1):

there is no GCP native solution, and I will have to move to the AWS API Gateway.

AWS can generate up to 10000 api keys, but they also have a way to implement a custom authorizer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html.

The custom authorizer method is exactly what I am looking for and someone has submitted this feature request to the GCP API Gateway team: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/226426383